# Eclipse. How to share editor templates with other users in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

we are working in group using Eclipse and programming in JAVA, and everyone has their own Editor Templates. I know that you can export/import the templates but can we share the templates automatically? Can I create/modify a template and share it automatically with other users, without to use import/export? Do you know any plug-in?

[image]

Comment: I don't think eclipse having `user` concept, like a multi-user server

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anyway to accomplish what you want automatically.

You could add the template files into your source code repository.  Let new team members know to import from there and/or send an email out when you make changes to the template.

Comment: I don't know why this perfectly reasonable response was downvoted but I upvoted it just to even the score.

Comment: @SteveCohen It is probably because OP was asking about sharing templates automatically while this answer shows how to do it manually. So it kind of *doesn't answer the question*.

Comment: @Pshemo - the answer implies that automatic template sharing is not possible, hence it is a valid answer.

Comment: @SteveCohen "*I don't know of anyway to accomplish...*" != "*it is impossible*" IMO.

Comment: @Pshemo - Pedantic much?

Comment: @SteveCohen Nope, rational. If I don't know how to do something it doesn't mean it can't be done. It is simple as that.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ftext%2Ftemplates%2Fpersistence%2FTemplateStore.html) to the API if the OP wants to build their own plugin or try and figure out where the actual templates are stored.

Comment: @Pshemo - so just saying nothing is preferable to a putatively informed opinion that there is no reasonably easy way to do it?  I have often abandoned such efforts when told this, and been glad to forget about such bees in my bonnet.  If I were the original questioner, I would appreciate such an answer.  And I've also accepted such advice, only to reject it later when I learned how to do the thing.  While this did lead me to downvote my original upvote in this instance, I would not give a downvote on principle unless I knew for sure that the answer was wrong.

Comment: @SteveCohen I am not saying that this answer is not useful, nor was I the person who downvoted it. I was just answering your "*I don't know why this perfectly reasonable response was downvoted*" comment with *possible* reason for downvote, which could be that *technically* this post doesn't answer the question (there is no "it is impossible" nor "it may be possible but don't do it because" part), but it only describes how to simplify manual approach.